# handling Any within a protocol buffer with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to handle some generic Message values within a wrapping protocol buffer (with nodejs):

```
message MessageWrapper {
    string id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any wrapped_message = 2;
    ....
}
```

as part of this, I have to pack() the Any:

```
const wrapper = new MessageWrapper();
const wrappedMessage = new Any();
wrappedMessage.pack(msg.serializeBinary(), msgType);
```

The heart of the problem is the msgType.  If I was using java, I could get the msg.getDescriptorForType(), but javascript doesn't seem to support that.. level of self description.  Outside of manually supplying the string type url, how does one get it?

Addendum: To be honest I'm not sure what the msgType of pack() is used for.  It seems I can put any string value in there and packing and unpacking seem to work fine.  What's it for?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [there](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#any). I'm no expert but I believe this fully qualified name (`msgType` in your case) is here for giving an additional check in the `unpack` (see the unpack @Returns in the documentation).

Comment: @ClémentJean yep, I stared at that for a bit.  However, this example just shows the problem.... 'foo.Bar' is hard coded into the code.  In a way, the whole point of an 'Any' is because I don't actually know the type of object I'm trying to wrap.  In java I could just ask the object I'm wrapping to tell me its type.  But for whatever reason the javascript protobuf stuff doesn't support this metadata (getDescriptorForType for example).

Comment: could you give us more context on how you compile your protobuf ?